# Swift how to do appearance of uiview slide left to right

Tags: xcode, swift, swipe, slide

I designed some UIView that interactive each other. But when a view appear always slide from right to left (default).
But i want it appears left to right some case (e.g i swipe right).
How i cant do it from Swift code?

Updated

I found a solution for this problem

```
            let slideInFromLeftTransition = CATransition()
            // Customize the animation's properties
            slideInFromLeftTransition.type = kCATransitionPush
            slideInFromLeftTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
            slideInFromLeftTransition.duration = 0.5
            slideInFromLeftTransition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            slideInFromLeftTransition.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved

            // Add the animation to the View's layer
            self.navigationController?.view.layer.addAnimation(slideInFromLeftTransition, forKey: "slideInFromLeftTransition")
```

This solved.

Comment: Please, paste your code on your question.

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question - that works better than putting your solution in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in swift 4.2:

```
func transitionVc(vc: UIViewController, type: CATransitionSubtype) {
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.3
        transition.type = CATransitionType(rawValue: "push")
        transition.subtype = type
        self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    }
```

Use these in the following way:

```
let viewController = YourViewController()

transitionVc(vc: viewController!, type: .fromLeft)

transitionVc(vc: viewController, type: .fromRight)
```